# When swiping on cell, it moves some label items

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is a bit odd. When I swipe on my cell to report an offensive post sometimes label and imageview items move around. I've attached a gif of the situation.

[image]

The following is my code for said action.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?  {
    // 1

    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Report" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        // 2

        let shareMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Offensive?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let twitterAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Nevermind", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

        shareMenu.addAction(twitterAction)
        shareMenu.addAction(cancelAction)


        self.presentViewController(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    // 3
    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 86.0/255, green: 199.0/255, blue: 217.0/255, alpha: 0.0)


    // 5
    return [shareAction]
}
```

I'm VERY confused as to why this is happening.